# pull the image down so that it is edged by hyper text

Tags: html, css

Is there a css way to make the image wrapped by the hyper text (text with html) from the left side? The height of the image is less than the height of the html text (html text means the **ordered list**, **h1** and so on) and it is below the first line of the text . Everything is wrapped into the **div**.

The code is here:

**css code:**

```
#container{
    width: 400px;
    background: yellow;
}
#floated{
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

**html code:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="floated">
        <img src="http://tiny.cc/63bb5x" alt="">
    </div>

    <h4>this text should wrap the image the same way</h2>
    <h5>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</h5>
    <ol>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

[And you can see it as it is now here (jsFiddle).](http://jsfiddle.net/25ac1ujs/1/)

http://jsfiddle.net/25ac1ujs/1/

**Again, I need to pull the image slightly down (lets say for 100px). As result, the space above the image should be filled by the text the same way as it is now below the image.**

Any ideas how to do that? 
Padding or margin I've tried to apply doesn't work as the text does not appear in the empty space.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use a pseudo and clear:

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  background: yellow;
}
#container:before {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  /* or left */
  height: 7em;
  /* or what ever you need */
}
#floated {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  clear: right;
  /* or left if pseudo floats left */
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
#container {
  text-align: center;
}
ol {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="floated">
    <img src="http://tiny.cc/63bb5x" alt="">
  </div>

  <h4>this text should wrap the image the same way</h2>
    <h5>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</h5>
    <ol>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<div id="container">
 <h4>this text should wrap the image the same way</h2>
<h5>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</h5>
    <img id="floated" src="http://tiny.cc/63bb5x" alt="">  
<ol>
    <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
    <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
    <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
    <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
    <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
    <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
    <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
    <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
    <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
    <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
    <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
    <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
    <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
    <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
    <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
    <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the floated div below the h5 tag:

```
<div id="container">    
    <h4>this text should wrap the image the same way</h2>
    <h5>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</h5>
    <div id="floated">
        <img src="http://tiny.cc/63bb5x" alt="Butterfly">
    </div>
    <ol>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
        <li>this text should wrap the image the same way</li>
        <li>and the image should be positioned a little bit lower</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xL8j4xpt/